# Vimscript - displaying string value in shell

Tags: vim

Consider the function,

```
function! Test()
    :let aString = "I'm a string!"
    :!echo aString
endfunction
```

Now entering `:call Test()` pipes the following to BASH:

```
aString

Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

How can I `:!echo` the value of `aString`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, got it working finally:

```
function! Test() 
   :!clear
   :let aString = 'I\''m a string\!'
   :execute "!echo " . aString
endfunction
```